# Why does my D3/topojson SVG not render with queue.js?

Tags: json, svg, d3.js, topojson, queue.js

I am attempting to create a world map with D3.js and have multiple CSV files load separately via queue.js. However, I am unable to render the json geometries, let alone able to attach CSV values to the path id.

Without the queue.js method, the SVG loads perfectly in the browser with this method:

```
     d3.json("world-50m.json", function(error, world) {

       svg.append("g")  
        .selectAll("path")
          .data(topojson.feature(world,world.objects.countries).features)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class","land")
          .attr("d", path)
       })
```

But the queue.js method I followed [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) does not render the SVG.

First:

```
    queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "world-50m.json")
    //.defer(d3.csv, "gni.csv", function(d) {rateById.set(d.id, +d.value);})
      .await(ready);
```

Then:

```
      function ready(error, world){
         svg.append("g")  
          .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(world,world.objects.countries).features)
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "land")
        //  .attr("class", function(d) {return quantize(rateById.get(d.id));})
            .attr("d", path)

       }
```

Can someone please advise me as to what mistake I may have made? 
This is a snippet of the json file structure:

```
            {
      "type":"Topology",
      "transform":{
        "scale":[0.03600360036003601,0.017366249624962495],
        "translate":[-180,-90]
      },
      "objects":{
        "countries":{
          "type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[
              {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5]],"id":"Afghanistan"},...
```

Comment: Did you verify that the data loads?

Comment: Lars Kotthoff, I am a novice. What I can tell you is that the console says " ReferenceError: queue is not defined "

Comment: With the original method that renders the SVG, the console states that "ReferenceError: g is not defined"

Comment: Sounds like you haven't included the `queue` library.

Comment: queue.v1.min.js script is loaded in the body with all the other scripts. Perhaps i should load it in the head?

Comment: You have to load it before executing your own code.

Comment: @user2759126: please share back the code or hack which solved your issue, it will thanks back the community helping you.